# How to scale a TopoJSON map in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, topojson

In [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/posox/1/edit), I have a d3.js chloropleth; unlike with a chart, when I change the height and width only the canvas size changes. How do I get the map to scale down as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the ["Let's Make a Map"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) Tutorial.

You want to define a projection for your path, depending on its type (likely albersUSA in your case):

```
  var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(800)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
```

You will need to translate the map as needed.

Comment: As soon as I add the line: ``var projection = d3.geo.albersUSA();``, I get no output at all, as in this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/posox/2/edit

Comment: @prooffreader Sorry - should have been: var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();